# How to import Azure API App which contains the basic authentication into API Management

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

I have deployed ASP.NETCore 2.1 code into Azure App Service with Basic Authentication. After that I have imported this API App into Azure API Management, then I can see all API actions in GUID format instead of original operations.

And tried to import the Azure API using Open API Specification, then it is giving the below error.

> The OpenAPI specification of this demo-api-dev App should contain
>   'host' value.

So, can anyone suggest on this

Comment: We need more info, to understand your problem. Do you use Swagger in your API App Service? Do you have an host value in your OpenAPI file?

Comment: @nmbrphi, Yes, I'm using Swagger for my API.

Comment: the openAPI file generated from swashbuckle is reacheable anonymously? Do this OpenAPI file have a property named 'host'? if so, is its value is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think the core issue here is that Swashbuckle doesn't auto-generate the host value in the Swagger file. I think the answer for this issue will be the same as the answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53793847/add-host-basepath-and-schemes-to-swagger-json-using-swashbuckle-aspnetcor)

Effectively, we need to give Swashbuckle a few more hints about configuring itself by giving it an `IDocumentFilter`.